# Validation rule, if the field is blank can be editable

Tags: validation-rule

I'm new to Salesforce and I have to **allow edit permission to some fields only if they are blank**. Otherwise they shouldn't be editable. My validation rule look like this for the moment, I'm a bit stuck. Probably I have to include ISCHANGED as well, but don't know exactly how

```
AND($Setup.Application_Control__c.Run_Validation_Rules__c = TRUE,
AND(NOT(ISBLANK(dfsle__CanManageAccount__c)  || ISBLANK(status)  || ISBLANK(username) )))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
AND( 
    ISCHANGED(field__c), 
    NOT( ISBLANK( PRIORVALUE(field__c) ) ) 
)
```

The Idea is to check the previous value of the field and fire validation rule

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_priorvalue.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_ischanged.htm&type=5

Thanks

Comment: I try it, but somehow I still can edit the field when there is already a value

Comment: Hi Livia, have you changed the field__c to your field. Could you please show your Updated Validation Rule

Comment: This is a custom setting to toggle rules on and off declaratively. $Setup.Application_Control__c.Run_Validation_Rules__c = TRUE, We use this to allow admins to get around validations and I'm assuming you're doing the same thing. It sounds like you're flagged as run validations = false at the user or profile level and it's not firing.

Comment: 1. Please remove $Setup.Application_Control__c.Run_Validation_Rules__c = TRUE this part and check that rule works for all users as expected. 2. please check values .Application_Control__c.Run_Validation_Rules__c and add this to rule

Comment: Hi! So I have this 4 fields. If one is blank you could edit it. This is how my VR looking now `AND(ISCHANGED(dfsle__CanManageAccount__c), 
    dfsle__CanManageAccount__c= FALSE,
    OR (ISCHANGED(dfsle__Username__c), ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(dfsle__Username__c) ) ), 
    OR (ISCHANGED(dfsle__Provisioned__c), ISBLANK( PRIORVALUE(dfsle__Provisioned__c) ) ),
    OR (ISCHANGED(dfsle__Status__c), ISPICKVAL(dfsle__Status__c, "") )
    )`       (The first field is a checkbox, and the last one is a picklist)

Comment: Hi, I assume your rule should be OR ( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) where 1 is AND (changed, false) - (you do not want to change back to false I think), 2,3,4 is AND (field changed, NOT prev blank). Does this help?

Comment: Make sens, thank you. I think it should look something like this `OR(
AND(ISCHANGED(dfsle__CanManageAccount__c), dfsle__CanManageAccount__c= FALSE),
ISCHANGED(dfsle__Username__c), ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(dfsle__Username__c) ) ,
ISCHANGED(dfsle__Provisioned__c), ISBLANK( PRIORVALUE(dfsle__Provisioned__c) ) ,
AND (ISCHANGED(dfsle__Status__c), NOT(ISPICKVAL(dfsle__Status__c, "") ) )
)` Now I can't edit the fileds, BUT not even when blank

Comment: OR( 
 AND(ISCHANGED(dfsle__CanManageAccount__c),dfsle__CanManageAccount__c= FALSE), 
AND (ISCHANGED(dfsle__Username__c),NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(dfsle__Username__c)))),AND ( ISCHANGED(dfsle__Provisioned__c), NOT(ISBLANK( PRIORVALUE(dfsle__Provisioned__c) )) ) , 
 AND (ISCHANGED(dfsle__Status__c), NOT(ISPICKVAL(dfsle__Status__c, "") ) ) 
)

Comment: This works well, beside for the picklist value but I will figured out and update this. Thank you!!

Comment: Update for picklist field :  PRIORVALUE(dfsle__Status__c) <> ''